# need to split the string based on the keyword

Tags: regex, python-3.x

```
string = """Hello World A \n Block1 \n Block2 \n \n Hello World B \n Block1 \n Block2"""
```

I want to split the string into two parts using regular expression in python, in which the first part should Contain the block Hello World A till Hello World B and the second part should contain the block from Hello World B till the end of the string.

I tried `re.findall(`) , but that didn't fetch me expected results. I want to know which regular expression statement can be used in this?

Comment: i tried as string_list =  re.findall(r'(?s)Hello World A.*?Hello World B',string). But this didn't fetch me expected results.

Comment: Expected result is  string_list = ['Hello World A \n  Block1 \n Block2 \n ' , Hello World B \n Block1 \n Block2' ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can try using `re.findall` in DOT ALL mode:

```
string = "Hello World A \n Block1 \n Block2 \n \n Hello World B \n Block1 \n Block2"
result = re.findall("Hello World.*?(?=Hello World|$)", string, re.DOTALL)
print(result)

['Hello World A \n Block1 \n Block2 \n \n ', 'Hello World B \n Block1 \n Block2']
```

Here is the pattern I used:

```
Hello World.*?(?=Hello World|$)
```

This matches `Hello World`, followed by anything provided that we don't consume another `Hello World`, *or* the very end of the string.  DOT ALL mode is necessary because we want `.*` to be able to match and consume across newlines.

Comment: can you please explain this part " (?=Hello World|$) " and why DOTALL mode is used?